# how to send text file created from android studio

Tags: java, android, text, drive, txt

i have saved some data in a .txt in the app file directory using this way, the name is in FILE_NAME variable which is string.

```
public void save() 
{
        mEditText = findViewById(R.id.data);
        String text = mEditText.getText().toString();
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(output.getBytes());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Saved to " + getFilesDir() + "/" + FILE_NAME,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Now i want to get the data from this .txt file and i'm trying to find a way to do it. It has a lot of lines of information in so it will be convenient if i can send the file directly to my email, upload it on google drive or any other way to get it completely.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing

Comment: is there any example of sharing a file or saving it to drive?